# Looking for Good Online PL/SQL Exercises with Solution

Tags: oracle, plsql

Are there any good online resources for PL/SQL exercises? Preferably, I am looking for more advanced exercises. Most of the exercises I have found online have been fairly simple without delving deep into the language.

Comment: Have you tried [Oracle Base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/plsql/articles-plsql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest 2 sites/(sugiero 2 sitios):

[devgym.oracle.com](http://devgym.oracle.com)

[plsqlchallenge.oracle.com](https://plsqlchallenge.oracle.com)